# The expire time of QR code

Tags: php, html, qr-code

I am currently working on QR code generator. I would like to generate a QR code which will expire after an hour. Should I have to make the QR code to link to a website with php script? Or I could make it to set expired time at the QR code? Thanks for help.

Comment: You should consider that having the expire time in the QR Code makes it much easier to _hack_ it.

Comment: You cant expire an image :/ you could put a code which expires serverside but then it can still be decoded then just forged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A QR code is, in itself, simply a text string that can be read by a camera.  Text strings, in themselves, don't expire.

So, your QR code will need to contain some sort of expiring code.  For example, you could put this kind of string into your QR code

```
 https://wee.example.com/expire.php?code=abcd1234876ce067e
```

It would look like this.

[image]

The code (`abcd1234876ce067e` in my example) is a randomly generated text string. It resists attack by cybercrooks because valid codes are hard to guess.

Then you write a little php program (called expire.php in this example) that looks up the code in a database. The codes table contains rows with the randomly generated code value and an expiration timestamp.  If the code doesn't exist in the database, or its expiration time has passed, you ignore it. Otherwise you do whatever needs to be done with an unexpired code.

Notice there are also a few URL shortening services offering expiration. You could read this. https://www.guidingtech.com/15120/temporary-short-urls-expiry-date/  You could use one of these services to obtain a expiring short URL, then put it into the QR code.

Comment: The URL shortening services are good, but I am currently working on php coding. So is it possible to make those services into code form in order for me to proceed?

Comment: And i would like to ask，how can I generate the random string for the code？I would like to generate every different qr code after i clicked a button to make sure it is unique.@O.Jones

Comment: There are plenty of ways to make random text strings. Here's just one example. https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5382685 . Use your favorite search engine to find `php random text string`.